# rename the "name" value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas

Here is the code that I am working on:

```
import pandas as pd
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
def dividend(stocks):
    for sName in stocks:
        print(sName)
        print('Dividend History: ')
        df = si.get_dividends(sName, '01-01-2019').iloc[:, :1]
        #df.rename(columns={'2019-02-20 00:00:00': '2019-02-20'}, inplace = True)
        df.to_excel("1.xlsx")
        print(df.iloc[0])

stocks = ['MSFT']
dividend(stocks)
```

the output from the excel file:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16N9P.png)

I would like to get rid of the "00:00:00"s.

I have tried using .rename and vectorization and neither seems to work(I might be doing it wrong)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column with no name, looking like dates with hour part, in your
source DataFrame, is probably the **index** of *object* type (actually
a string).

To confirm it, run `df.index` and you should get something like:

```
Index(['2019-02-20 00:00:00', '2019-05-15 00:00:00', '2019-08-14 00:00:00',
       '2019-11-20 00:00:00', '2020-02-19 00:00:00', '2020-05-20 00:00:00'],
      dtype='object')
```

Note *'object'* as *dtype*.

To get rid of the time part, convert the index to *datetime64* (native
*pandasonic* date / time type):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Now when you run `df.index` and you should get something like:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-02-20', '2019-05-15', '2019-08-14', '2019-11-20',
               '2020-02-19', '2020-05-20'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Note that this time *dtype* is *'datetime64[ns]'*.

When you print *df*, you should get:

```
            dividend
2019-02-20      0.46
2019-05-15      0.46
2019-08-14      0.46
2019-11-20      0.51
2020-02-19      0.51
2020-05-20      0.51
```

Under the hood the index actually still has the time part, but *Pandas*
is clever enough not to print it when all date parts are zero.

Comment: It didn't solve the zeros that are still in the excel sheet. Figured it out with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` Thanks!

Comment: In my original solution, the index **did** contain the time part, but *Pandas* suppressed its printout. Your solution causes that zeroes (the time part) are removed and the type of the index is still *object* (actually string). This difference can be significant, when you attempt to perform "datetime related" operations, e.g. resampling. But for "ordinary" presentation of data your solution is OK.